# Angular2 route resolve always returns array instead of single object

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular-services, resolve

I'm retrieving user information to display a profile page and I make use of a route resolve to do this, but the resolve method puts the user in an array for some reason. How can I make the resolve return the single object?

*All the services, modules, resolves and components are declared and provided*

Model:

```
/**
 * Builds a user from the provided parameters
 * @param {string} id of the user
 * @param {string} username of the user
 * @param {string} password of the user
 * @param {string} apiKey of the user
 * @param {string[]} roles of the user to give certain rights
 */
export class User {
    id: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    apiKey: string;
    roles: string[];

    constructor(id: string, username: string, password: string, apiKey: string, roles: string[]) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Service method:

```
findByApiKey(): Observable<User> {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/smartask.usersv2+json');
    headers.append('api-key', this.authenticationService.getApikey());

    const options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });

    const url = `${this.url}?apikey=${this.authenticationService.getApikey()}`;
    return this.http.get(url, options)
        .map((response: Response) => {
            return (<any>response.json()).map(user => {
                return new User(
                    user.id,
                    user.username,
                    user.password,
                    user.apiKey,
                    user.roles
                );
            });
        }, {headers: headers});
}
```

Resolve class:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve} from '@angular/router';
import {User} from '../models/user.model';
import {UserService} from '../providers/user.service';


@Injectable()
export class UserResolve implements Resolve<User> {

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        return this.userService.findByApiKey();
    }
}
```

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../../models/user.model';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile',
    templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    user: User;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = this.route.snapshot.data['profile'];
        console.log('user', this.user);
    }

}
```

And the result of the console.log is [image]

Comment: You should look at the raw response of your api. That's most likely an array containing one user object

Comment: @PierreDuc This is indeed the problem... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, the problem is the API returning an array containing a user object. If you cannot change that, you can change your `map` to this:

```
return this.http.get(url, options)
    .map(response => response.json()) // this is no longer necessary in latest angular
    .map(user => user && user[0])
    .map(userData => userData && new User(
       userData.id,
       userData.username,
       userData.password,
       userData.apiKey,
       userData.roles
    ), {headers: headers});
```